# ClickHouse Tuple to columns

Tags: clickhouse

Is it possible to transform tuple into columns in ClickHouse?

`SELECT tuple(1,'a')` gives

```
  | tuple(1,'a') |
–-|--------------|
0 | (1,'a')      |
```

How to transform it into result of two columns?

```
  | 0 | 1   |
–-|---------|
0 | 1 | 'a' |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1, 'a')**.1** 
.tuple_element_index or function tupleElement

```sql
SELECT
    (1, 'a').1,
    (1, 'a').2

/*
┌─tupleElement(tuple(1, 'a'), 1)─┬─tupleElement(tuple(1, 'a'), 2)─┐
│                              1 │ a                              │
└────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: So there's no way to expand automatically? Considering all tuples have same amount of elements.

Comment: In modern CH it can be done with untuple. SELECT untuple((1, 'a'))

Comment: any idea how to make column names numeric instead of  eg `divide(multiply(val, 8), 300)` when using `utuple((val * 8 / 300))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [untuple](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/tuple-functions#untuple):

```sql
SELECT untuple(tuple(1,'a')) as "ex_tuple"

/*
┌─ex_tuple.1─┬─ex_tuple.2─┐
│          1 │ a          │
└────────────┴────────────┘
*/
```